# Threads synchronising not working

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I am trying to implement synchronization using the following code, but its not working as expected.

```
class Callme extends Thread{

    synchronized void call( ) {

    System.out.print("[" + "Hello");

    try {

    Thread.sleep(1000);

    } catch(InterruptedException e) {

    System.out.println("Interrupted");
    }

    System.out.println("]");

    }


    public void run() 
    {
    call();
    }

}


public class Threads {

    static void main(String args[]) {

    Callme target = new Callme();

    Callme target2 = new Callme();

    target.start();

    target2.start();
}}
```

The output should be [Hello][Hello] but its something like [Hello[Hello]] which is not synchronized.

Comment: Add `static` before `synchronized void call( ) {`.

Comment: Why should the output be `[Hello][Hello]`? Whatever reasoning led you to that expectation is the problem.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Because call() is a synchronized method and another thread "target2 "cannot access it until, the current thread "target1" is accessing the call() method.

Comment: @toadalskiii - `synchronized void call( )` will take a lock on the current object (you have 2 different objects). So you have 2 different locks

Comment: @TheLostMind so, how should I call the method to get [Hello][Hello] output. How to create two threads using single object.

Comment: @toadalskiii - use a common lock (`static synchronized`) or some other lock

Comment: @toadalskiii A "synchronized method" is one that locks the object it's a method on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code is working fine IMO and in fact there is not a synchronizing issue there,

**Why not?:**

Every Object of the class thread is calling their own `call` method, and printing it when it should, they are in fact trying to get the same resource, (the System.out.print) but that is not synchronized....
so it is a totally correct behavior that you get something like

> [Hello[Hello]]

in you output.

Comment: How to create two threads using single object and call the call() method to give [Hello][Hell] output.

Comment: Actually, System.out.println() _is_ synchronized, which explains why the program never prints out anything like `[He[lHleollo]]`.  But just because a program calls `synchronized` methods doesn't mean that the program itself will be thread safe.  The synchronization has to happen at the right level.

Answer (score 1):

Well a lot of helping answers come on your way. But I think its better if you can understand the basic concept of the synchronization of threads. 
So when you synchronize a method like what you have done above, it means that the particular thread that want to execute the particular synchronized method does need the lock of the object. So once the object lock has been taken from another thread, then a particular thread will have to wait until the first thread releases the lock of the object.

But here you are using two separate threads and two separate objects. so obviously what you get is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The output should be [Hello[Hello]],Because of you new two thread，target，target2，and the call() is  the class Callme‘s member method 。so target and
target2 use their own call() . if your want to Thread synchronized,you need
make target and target2 invoke the same method call().

for example：

```
enter code here
```

public class Callme extends Thread {

```
    public void run() 

    {

     Threads.call();
    }
```

}

public class Threads {

```
synchronized static void  call( ) {

    System.out.print("[" + "Hello");

    try {

    Thread.sleep(1000);

    } catch(InterruptedException e) {

    System.out.println("Interrupted");
    }

    System.out.println("]");

    }
public  static void main(String args[]) {

     Callme target = new Callme();

     Callme target2 = new Callme();

     target.start();
     target2.start();
     }
```

}